# AngualrJS - Execute code after digest cycle in ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a form which has several input elements.  The input elements value are set to scope variables.  There is a button with the ng-click directive which contains code that uses some logic(calling other methods from scope variables) to determine and set the input elements value via scope variables:

```
<input value="{{variableToBeSetOnButtonClick}} ...>
<button ng-click="setFormInputValues();submitForm();" ...>

myApp.directive('...', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element) {

        var setFormInputValues = function() {
            scope.variableToBeSetOnButtonClick = scope.objFromOtherDirective.getValue();
        };
        var submitForm = function() {
            $(element).find("form")[0].submit()
        };

}
```

The problem with this is the $apply doesn't execute until after all the ng-click functions have executed, so the input value isn't set yet when the submit() is called.

Perhaps there's a better way to do this?  The only solution I could find is to put a $watch on variableToBeSetOnButtonClick, which calls the submit(), and trying to deregister the $watch in that callback, but this seems hacky.

Comment: call setFormInputValues inside submitForm (before the actual 'submit()') and call just submitForm with ng-click

Comment: Definitely be cautious of your use of $watch as I believe there are some performance issues associated with its overuse. Usually there is a better way to do it as you have mentioned.

Comment: Calling setFormInputValues inside submitForm doesn't work.  The digest cycle doesn't complete until after submitForm so the input value is not set yet.

Comment: Also, I strongly recommend using the scope variable you declared on your directive function instead of the traditional var from javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `$timeout()` before submitting the form:

```
myApp.directive('...', function($timeout) {
    ...     
    var submitForm = function() {
        $timeout(function () {
             $(element).find("form")[0].submit();
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: This seems also a bit hacky and introduces a possible race condition?  If the form submit is fired off before the digest cycle, then the input value is not set.

Comment: Did you test, does this approach work? Using `$timeout()` is the usual method with Angular to let the current digest cycle finish and then do something. So, the form submit would be fired off AFTER the digest cycle.

Comment: Guess I'm wrong.  It does work and the documentation does indicate $timeout is used for scheduling things after deferred actions(digest cycle) have completed.